# Django Serializer How to loop over dictionary value and return in serializer

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-serializer

I have following dictionary inside list

```
self.passengers = [{'first_name':'Harry','last_name':'kane'},{'first_name':'cristiano','last_name':'aviero'}
```

I Have set my serializer as following

```
class PassengerSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField()
    last_name = serializers.CharField()


class TicketDetailSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    passenger = PassengerDetailSerializer(many=True)
```

I have set my code as following to extract passenger data

```
'passenger': [{
               'last_name': [passenger['last_name'] for passenger in self.passengers],
                'first_name': [passenger['first_name'] for passenger in self.passengers]
                }],
```

But I am only getting firstname ->'harry' and lastname-> kane what shall I do next to get all dictionary of first name and last name is self.passengers?
I am getting output as:

```
"passenger": [
        {
            "lastname": "['kane', 'aviero']",
            "firstname": "['harry', 'cristiano']"
        }
    ]
```

I want output as

```
"passenger": [
            {
                "lastname": "kane",
                "firstname": "harry"
            },
            {
                "lastname": "aviero",
                "firstname": "cristiano"
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Did you miss an s? self.passengers = [{'fi... vs passenger = PassengerDetailSerializer(many=True)

Comment: no no thats not a problem I just kept a part of code so it got misplaced

Comment: What’s the difference between your input and desired output?

Comment: I have mentioned there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'passenger': [{
               'last_name': passenger['last_name'],
                'first_name': passenger['first_name']
              } for passenger in self.passengers ]
```

Comment: still got the same output

Comment: That's very unlikely. Maybe something else is wrong.

Comment: The only difference i see between the `self.passengers`  and the expected output is that there are no `_`s in the keys of the output, rest all is same. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: that is not a problem in variable as i just replaced my main code variables in my question with varaibles but in my ide it have done as answer at the end it gets list comprehesnion that is why the value are in list